# OpenCV face deteciton returns too many faces

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I have a little problem. I am trying to make face detection via Kinect v1.I get data from kinect and convert it to OpenCV mat. Then I am trying to detect faces in my image but the function return face.size() = cca 250000000. Do you know where is the problem ?

```
void getKinectData(GLubyte* dest) {
    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame; //structure of frame ( number,res etc )
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect; //pointer to actual data
    if (sensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(rgbStream, 0, &imageFrame) < 0) return;
    INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture; // manages the frame data
    texture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);
    IplImage* image = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(COLOR_WIDTH, COLOR_HIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0) // pitch - how many bytes are in each row of the frame
    {
        BYTE* curr = (BYTE*)LockedRect.pBits;
        cvSetData(image, curr, LockedRect.Pitch);
        const BYTE* dataEnd = curr + (widthX*heightX) * 4;
        while (curr < dataEnd) {
            *dest++ = *curr++;
        }
    }
    //cvShowImage("color image", image);
    m = cv::cvarrToMat(image).clone();
    DetectAndDisplay(m);

    texture->UnlockRect(0);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(rgbStream, &imageFrame);

}

void DetectAndDisplay(cv::Mat frame)
{
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

    cv::Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);
    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(24, 24));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height / 2);
        ellipse(frame, center, cv::Size(faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].height / 2), 0, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);

        cv::Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]);
        std::vector<cv::Rect> eyes;
        /*
        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

        for (size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++)
        {
            Point eye_center(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width / 2, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height / 2);
            int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25);
            circle(frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);
        }*/
    }
    //-- Show what you got
    imshow(window_name, frame);
}
```

Comment: i think you are using VS and your configuration is wrong

Comment: have you printed a single image? Only to check how it looks like just in case it has nothing to do with what you expect. I see in your code you commented the line out `cvShowImage("color image", image)`, have you tried it already?

Comment: Yes i tried it. The image is OK. I tried to turn it into Release mode and it find only 1 face ? Is it normal ? why is different to have it in Debug or Release ? I never have problem with this. @sturkmen Maybe you are right. But how can i fix it ?

Comment: i don't use VS maybe looking [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34991595/5294258) will give you a clue (#if defined(NDEBUG)...)

Comment: The actual problem is C++ has no standard ABI and linking to a `release` library with a `debug` configuration causes errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know this old, but I had a similar problem, so I thought others may benefit.

Linking with the release opencv_objdetect library during a debug build will lead to detectMultiScale() returning an enormous vector containing hundreds of thousands of erroneous rectangles. Here's how to fix it in Visual Studio 2017 (I'm using OpenCV version 3.2, so adjust the names of the libraries mentioned to correspond with the version you are using):

1. **Project | (your project name) Properties...** (or right click on
   project in Solution Explorer & select Properties)
2. Change **Configuration** to **Debug** and **Platform** to **All Platforms** (or you can
   repeat these steps individually for each Debug platform)
3. Go to **Linker | Input** and make sure **opencv_objdetect320d.lib** is in the
   **Addition Dependencies** list and remove **opencv_objdetect320.lib** if
   it's there.
4. Repeat the above steps for **Configuration** == **Release**, but
   this time make sure **Linker | Input** includes **opencv_objdetect320.lib**
   (no trailing d in the name) in the **Addition Dependencies** list and remove
   **opencv_objdetect320d.lib** if it's there.